# Error initializing guard-livereload

Tags: windows, guard, livereload

I'm trying to install guard live reload on windows.  So far I've got guard installed and working via bundler.  But after installing the livereload gem and trying `guard init livereload` and `bundler exec guard init livereload` I get the following:

`10:12:46 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/livereload' or '~/.guard/templates/live
reload' or find class Guard::Livereload`

Comment: Me too, Did you find any solutions ??

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue when I tried running `guard init livereload` but it works just fine when you run `bundle exec guard init` alone without `livereload` word at the end. You can also read more about the [Guard Gem](https://github.com/guard/guard#readme). Maybe this will work for you too. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and adding to my Guardfile

```rb
require 'em/pure_ruby'
```

resolved that error.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
group :development do
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
end
```

Then run `bundle install` again.

Answer (score -1):

I was seeing the same error on an M1 Mac. [This](https://fand.jp/rails-7-error-that-unable-to-load-the-event-machine-c-extension/) post helped me find the solution.

In the Gemfile:

```rb
gem "eventmachine", git: "https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git", branch: "master"
```